# Android Application getting restarted when Camera is on and taken picture

Tags: android, cordova, mobile-application

I am workling on mobile application developed using DOJO toolkit and Apache Cordova API To handle device specific code like Camera . Application is getting restarted when camera is launched and taken picture ,once we save the picture , the application is started from the login screen.Again application is working absolutely fine in Samsung Galaxy tablet having Android v 4.1.2 .But failing in Samsung Galaxy S3 android version 4.1.2 .Appreciate your help.

Thanks
Krishna

Answer (score 1):

this happens on memory strapped devices.  Have you tried the foregroundcamera plugin as an alternative?
https://code.google.com/p/foreground-camera-plugin/